# Saml Assertion AttributeValue without Namespace

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml

Currently below java code is generating namespaces inside

```
SAMLObjectBuilder attrBuilder = (SAMLObjectBuilder) getSAMLBuilder().getBuilder(Attribute.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
         Attribute attrFirstName = (Attribute) attrBuilder.buildObject();
         attrFirstName.setName(name);
         attrFirstName.setNameFormat("xyz");
         // Set custom Attributes
         XMLObjectBuilder stringBuilder = getSAMLBuilder().getBuilder(XSString.TYPE_NAME);
         XSString attrValueFirstName = (XSString) stringBuilder.buildObject(AttributeValue.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, XSString.TYPE_NAME);
         attrValueFirstName.setValue(value);
         attrFirstName.getAttributeValues().add(attrValueFirstName);
```

This generates below xml doc for me :-

```
<saml:Attribute Name="xyz" NameFormat="xyz">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">
                CustomValue</saml:AttributeValue>
```

Whereas I want the output like below without namespaces, is it possible by any ways ?

```
<saml:Attribute Name="xyz" NameFormat="xyz"><saml:AttributeValue>CustomValue</saml:AttributeValue>
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Third party processing engine is poorly desined and not accepting or unable to read assertion value with xsi:type="xs:string"... looking for some workaround or possible ways.

Comment: Then they aren't SAML-compliant and should fix their engine.